# How to subtract 30 days from sysdate and exclude hours

Tags: sql, oracle

i am trying to subtract 30 days from sysdate

The query that i am using is  (sysdate - 30). However, this includes the current sysdate hours and minute.

i want it to include all data where sysdate is -30 without specificing the hour and minute.

Comment: google `trunc` function

Comment: Do you really like to subtract 30 days or one months? In this case you may use `ADD_MONTHS(trunc(sysdate), -1)`

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_Date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:Mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate,
  2         sysdate - 30 thirty_days_ago,
  3         trunc(sysdate - 30) truncated
  4  from dual;

SYSDATE             THIRTY_DAYS_AGO     TRUNCATED
------------------- ------------------- -------------------
26.09.2019 11:10:18 27.08.2019 11:10:18 27.08.2019 00:00:00

SQL>
```

If you want to *display* it without time component, either `alter session` again (but using different data format, e.g. `dd.mm.yyyy`), or apply `TO_CHAR` function:

```
SQL> select to_char(trunc(sysdate - 30), 'dd.mm.yyyy') without_time
  2  from dual;

WITHOUT_TI
----------
27.08.2019

SQL>
```